# How to integrate Groovy DSL in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, apache-kafka

I am developing a dsl which allows to send and receive messages from kafka broker, I developed a kafka producer and consumer with spring boot kafka starter and I was wondering if it is possible to pass its components to the dsl via the groovy Binding class and will groovy find the necessary dependencies.

```
@Autowired
private KafkaProducer kafkaProducer;

@Autowired
private KafkaProducer kafkaConsumer;

Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setVariable("kafkaproducer",kafkaProducer);
binding.setVariable("kafkaconsumer",kafkaConsumer);

new GroovyShell(binding).evaluate(new File("DSL.txt").text);
```

Please give me an idea .

Comment: Could you please be more specific, what problem you are facing? The code there looks roughly like it should ron your script just fine? Do you get errors or does it not work as expected? Please add those errors or how it fails to the question.